# R - dplyr - How to mutate rows or divitions between rows

Tags: r, rows, dplyr

I found that dplyr is speedy and simple for aggregate and summarise data. But I can't find out how to solve the following problem with dplyr.

Given these data frames:

```
df_2017 <- data.frame(
  expand.grid(1:195,1:65,1:39), 
  value = sample(1:1000000,(195*65*39)),
  period = rep("2017",(195*65*39)),
   stringsAsFactors = F
)

df_2017 <- df_2017[sample(1:(195*65*39),450000),]

names(df_2017) <- c("company", "product", "acc_concept", "value", "period")

df_2017$company <- as.character(df_2017$company)
df_2017$product <- as.character(df_2017$product)
df_2017$acc_concept <- as.character(df_2017$acc_concept)
df_2017$value <- as.numeric(df_2017$value)

ratio_df <- data.frame(concept=c("numerator","numerator","numerator","denom", "denom", "denom","name"),
ratio1=c("1","","","4","","","Sales over Assets"),
ratio2=c("1","","","5","6","","Sales over Expenses A + B"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

where the columns in df_2017 are:

- *company*     = This is a categorical variable with companies from 1 to 195
- *product*     = This is a categorical, with home apliance products from 1 to 65. For example, 1 could be equal to irons, 2 to television, etc
- *acc_concept* = This is a categorical variable with accounting concepts from 1 to 39. For example, 1 would be equal to "Sales", 2 to "Total Expenses", 3 to Returns", 4 to "Assets, etc
- *value*       = This is a numeric variable, with USD from 1 to 100.000.000
- *period*      = Categorical variable. Always 2017

As the expand.grid implies, the combinations of *company - product - acc_concept* are never duplicated, but, It could happen that certains subjects have not every *company - product - acc_concept* combinations. That's why the code line "df_2017 <- df_2017[sample(1:195*65*39),450000),]", and that's why the output could turn out into NA (see below).

And where the columns in ratio_df are:

- *Concept* = which acc_concept corresponds to numerator, which one to
  denominator, and which is name of the ratio
- *ratio1* = acc_concept and name for ratio1
- *ratio2* = acc_concept and name for ratio2

**I want to calculate 2 ratios (ratio_df) between acc_concept, for each product within each company.**

For example:

I take the first ratio "acc_concepts" and "name" from ratio_df:

```
num_acc_concept   <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "numerator", 2]
denom_acc_concept <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "denom", 2]
ratio_name        <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "name", 2]
```

Then I calculate the ratio for one product of one company, just to show you want i want to do:

```
ratio1_value <- sum(df_2017[df_2017$company == 1 & df_2017$product == 1 & df_2017$acc_concept %in% num_acc_concept, 4]) / sum(df_2017[df_2017$company == 1 & df_2017$product == 1 & df_2017$acc_concept %in% denom_acc_concept, 4])
```

Output:

```
output <- data.frame(Company="1", Product="1", desc_ratio=ratio_name, ratio_value = ratio1_value, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

As i said before i want to do this for each product within each company

The output data.frame could be **something like this (ratios aren't the true ones because i haven't done the calculations yet)**:

```
company    product   desc_ratio              ratio_value
1           1        Sales over Assets           0.9303675
1           2        Sales over Assets           1.30
1           3        Sales over Assets           Nan
1           4        Sales over Assets           Inf
1           5        Sales over Assets           2.32
1           6        Sales over Assets           NA
.
.
.
1           1        Sales over Expenses A + B   3.25
.
.
.
2           1        Sales over Assets          0.256
```

and so on...

- NaN when ratio is 0 / 0
- Inf when ratio is number / 0
- NA when there is no data for certain company and product.

I hope i have made myself clear this time :)

Is there any way to solve this row problem with dplyr? Should I cast the df_2017 for mutating? In this case, which is the best way for casting?

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Do you really need a dataframe of 450k rows to explain your question? You can construct a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It's exactly the same, Ronak. However, the dataframe i'm working on is that size, so I need a solution with a good performance; not just a looping function.

Comment: There are times when specificity and accurate representation are required, certainly, but typically they are not required to address a need or method. It is often the case that the problem can be simplified significantly; this has many beneficial side-effects, including: (1) much more readable, with a higher likelihood somebody will read through your entire question in order to help you; (2) broader problem and solution, so others with similar-enough problems can extrapolate and learn sufficiently from them; and (3) perhaps you can apply what you learn in other places.

Comment: It was already simplified. Phiver understood it. The core of the problem is in the title. If you want to mutate rows, read this. I'll take into account your remakrs, anyway for my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it. At the end I timed the code on all of your records.

First create a function to create all the ratios. Do note, this function is only useful inside the dplyr code.

```
ratio <- function(data){
  result <- data.frame(desc_ratio = rep(NA, ncol(ratio_df) -1), ratio_value = rep(NA, ncol(ratio_df) -1))

  for(i in 2:ncol(ratio_df)){
    num   <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "numerator", i]
    denom <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "denom", i]
    result$desc_ratio[i-1] <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "name", i]
    result$ratio_value[i-1] <- sum(ifelse(data$acc_concept %in% num, data$value, 0)) / sum(ifelse(data$acc_concept %in% denom, data$value, 0))
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Using dplyr, tidyr and purrr to put everything together. First group by the data, nest the data needed for the function, run the function with a mutate on the nested data. Drop the not needed nested data and unnest to get your wanted output. I leave the sorting up to you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
output <- df_2017 %>%
  group_by(company, product, period) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(ratios = map(data, ratio)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest

output

# A tibble: 25,350 x 5
   company product period desc_ratio                ratio_value
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>                           <dbl>
 1 103     2       2017   Sales over Assets               0.733
 2 103     2       2017   Sales over Expenses A + B       0.219
 3 26      26      2017   Sales over Assets               0.954
 4 26      26      2017   Sales over Expenses A + B       1.01 
 5 85      59      2017   Sales over Assets               4.14 
 6 85      59      2017   Sales over Expenses A + B       1.83 
 7 186     38      2017   Sales over Assets               7.85 
 8 186     38      2017   Sales over Expenses A + B       0.722
 9 51      25      2017   Sales over Assets               2.34 
10 51      25      2017   Sales over Expenses A + B       0.627
# ... with 25,340 more rows
```

Time it took to run this code on my machine measured with `system.time`:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   6.75    0.00    6.81
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, phiver. That's was exactly what i wanted. I have learned some key functions from you.